# Using LINQ to XML to get specific descendants node value

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document I am trying to query with LINQ to XML. The XML is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <operation>
    <authentication>
      <username>redacted</username>
      <isauthenticated>true</<isauthenticated>>
    </authentication>
    <result>
      <status>success</status>
      <other-elements></<other-elements>
      <other-elements></<other-elements>
      <other-elements>
        <other-sub-elements></other-sub-elements>
        <other-sub-elements></other-sub-elements>
      </<other-elements>
    </result>
  </operation>
</response>
```

I am trying to read the value of the node `<status>` to determine if the API call was successful. I am having trouble putting together the LINQ syntax necessary to grab the value of the `<status` node. I thought I could use XPath syntax as such to grab the value.

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponse);
string returnValue = = xml.Descendants("result/status").Select(x => x.Name).ToString();
```

However, I am getting the following error ..

> The '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F, cannot be included in a name.

Comment: `xml.Descendants("status).Where(n => n.Parent.LocalName = "result")` or something along `xml.Descendants("result").Elements("result")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINQ-to-XML methods `Elements()` and `Descendants()` only deal with single names, not xpath-like paths. If you want to give an xpath expression, use the xpath extensions.

```cs
// using System.Xml.Linq;
var status = (string)xml.XPathSelectElement("//result/status");
```

Otherwise you need to build up an equivalent query using the methods correctly.

```cs
var status = (string)xml.Descendants("result").Elements("status").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<response>
  <operation>
    <authentication>
      <username>redacted</username>
      <isauthenticated>true</isauthenticated>
    </authentication>
    <result>
      <status>success</status>
    </result>
  </operation>
</response>

");

Boolean isSuccess;
String s = xdoc.Element("response").Element("operation").Element("result").Element("status").Value;

isSuccess = s == "success";
```

It gets the value of the `status` element and checks whether it is equal to a specific value; in this case, `isSuccess` will be `true`.